# Rigorous Linear Transformation Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

$T:V \rightarrow V$ 
We could also write: $T:V \rightarrow Im(T)$ 
**The question tells us that $Im(T)=Im(T^2)$**

It's intuitively obvious that this means that T then maps $Im(T)$ to itself so if you keep applying $T$ the codomain will still always be $Im(T)$ so $Im(T)=Im(T^2)=Im(T^3)=...$

$Im(T)=Im(T^n) \forall n$

How do I write this all out as a proof rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\geq 1$ is such that $T^{n}(V) = T(V)$, then $T^{n+1}(V) = T\circ T^{n}(V) = T(T(V)) = T^{2}(V) = T(V)$.

Comment: Why can you do this to a whole set? If you have a set $V$ writing $T(V), T^n(V)$  is all legal ? and playing with composition and powers like you would any single element in the set? why?

Comment: Because $T(V) := \{ T(x) \mid x \in V \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the composition
$$
V \stackrel {T^n} \to V \stackrel T \to V.
$$
We see $Im(T^{n+1}) = Im (T|_{Im(T^n)}) = Im(T|_{Im(T)})=Im(T^2)=Im(T)$ by induction.